# How to manage memory properly using Director class 1.4?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, coronasdk

I am using director class 1.4 for changing scene to scene and i am wondering if the director class manages memory automatically or do i have to manage them manualy removing and nilling out every thing?

I am using this code to check if the memories are cleared automatically and they aren't cleared automatically from what i see.
It leaks memory every time i change from one scene to another scene.

```
local monitorMem = function()
    collectgarbage()
    print( "MemUsage: " .. collectgarbage("count") )

    local textMem = system.getInfo( "textureMemoryUsed" ) / 1000000
        print( "TexMem:   " .. textMem )
    end
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", monitorMem )
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you found this link?

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/08/15/corona-sdk-memory-leak-prevention-101/

It is my understanding that all display objects that are added to the local group are automatically removed from memory, but runtime listeners, timers and transitions are not.